# Exporting Java project as runnable Jar: not doing anything

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

So I have a problem with exporting my eclipse project.
The project works perfectly when running it inside eclipse, but when exporting it, it doesn't do anything.

[image]

[image]

I can't post a third link since I have less than 10 reputation, but in there I chose my "main" as launch configuration, and "package required libraries.

When I double click the runnable Jar nothing happens, nothing pops up.. No message nothing.
When I run it using `java -jar smergy.jar` I receive

```
`C:\Users\Jean>java -jar Smergy.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at smergy.SmergyMain.<init>(SmergyMain.java:162)
        at smergy.SmergyMain$1.run(SmergyMain.java:50)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Comment: what happens when you run `java -jar yourjar.jar` from the commandline ?

Comment: Please don't use only screenshots, you can copy such details into your question as text. You have to check if your jar is valid, use either a zipping utility for this (Winzip, 7zip) or use the jar command like this: `jar -tvf smergy.jar`. If the file is correct it can be read and contains everything you exported before. And _please_ make sure that the jar is in the directory you issue any of the commands in.

Comment: Ok I get a "NullPointerException", lots of unknown sources, EventQueue, Here you can see it: https://gyazo.com/820cdf8cd6c761dfd2c324eadd42dd7c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the images are not being packaged into the jar. Or they are not being loaded. 
One way to deal with loading resources is using the Toolkit like this:
    `setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/package1/package2/dump.jpg")));`

Comment: I unzipped it and I can see all the images in the folder

Comment: What is in the line `smergy.SmergyMain.<init>(SmergyMain.java:162)`?

Comment: `Image imgBgRed = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Red.png")).getImage();`

Its weird that it indicates that line since its a random one along a lot of other images

Comment: Ok soooo.. I fixed it. I rebuilt the whole project from scratch and suddenly it worked! Magic..

Comment: Thank you very very much for the help!